# Use variable for filepath parameter of Start-Process

Tags: powershell

I'd like run a .exe which could be in a number of locations.

```
$runpath = "$servicepackfolder\SQLServer2008SP1-KB968369-IA64-ENU.exe"

Start-Process -FilePath $runpath -arg "/x:.\$buildfolder\PCU"
```

Or this way, specifying the WorkingDirectory:

```
Start-Process 'SQLServer2008SP1-KB968369-IA64-ENU.exe' -WorkingDirectory $servicepackfolder -arg "/x:.\$buildfolder\PCU"
```

But it seems the variables are not being interpreted as strings.

> Start-Process : This command cannot be
>   executed due to the error: The system
>   cannot find the file specified.

I am in the correct directory and if I take the output from the $runpath variable and substitute it for the variable in the Start-Process call, I get the expected behavior.

Will this work, or am I stuck hardcoding these paths.  Trying to automate the slipstream build process for SQL 2008.

Comment: Did you ever figure out if you could do this?

Answer (score 1):

I can duplicate the behavior you see *if* I add `-NoNewWindow` but if I don't specify that parameter it works as expected for my test case:

```
start-process sizeof.exe  -WorkingDirectory C:\temp -ArgumentList 1
```

The new window flashes up and goes away but I can see it is running the specified exe from my temp dir.

Comment: I'm trying to use a variable for the value of a parameter.  It looks like you have it hard coded there.

Comment: Using a variable would work just as well - `-ArgumentList $myvar`. Are you using `-NoNewWindow`?

Comment: @KeithHill - try replacing `sizeof.exe` with a variable that holds the same textual value.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never, but I've found a workaround for this when having the same issue, not sure if it is classed as a bug or not -

Powershell doesn't always handle un-escaped backslashes or quotes in the strings that are stored in a variable / created by string processing all that well for -FilePath, so for your line:

```
$runpath = "$servicepackfolder\SQLServer2008SP1-KB968369-IA64-ENU.exe"
```

Try the following (or equivalent) before using $runpath:

```
$cleanpath = $runpath.replace("\","\\").replace('"',"")
```

The .replace("\","\\").replace('"',"") escapes the slashes and eliminates the quotes that the string handling and passing introduce, which seems to clear this issue (for some cases).

Bit late for you I imagine but hopefully this helps other people googling for this one.