# `Start-Process` can not find file that exists in PATH, even when given absolut path to the file

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I am trying to use `Start-Process` in Powershell Core using a variable to specify what process to start. I know that `dotnet` is in my PATH so this works:

```bsh
$DotnetRunCommandApp = 'run --project path/to/my/project.csproj'
Start-Process dotnet -ArgumentList $DotnetRunCommandApp
```

However, when I try to move `dotnet` into a variable like this:

```bsh
$DotnetCommand = 'dotnet'
$DotnetRunCommandApp = 'run --project path/to/my/project.csproj'
Start-Process $DotnetCommand -ArgumentList $DotnetRunCommandApp
```

or even using the absolute path to `dotnet` like this:

```bsh
$DotnetCommand = Resolve-Path ((Get-Command dotnet).Source | Out-String -NoNewline)

if (-not (Test-Path $DotnetCommand)) {
  Write-Error "Can not find '$DotnetCommand'"
} else {
  Write-Debug "Found $DotnetCommand" # Logs "DEBUG: Found C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe"
}

$DotnetRunCommandApp = 'run --project path/to/my/project.csproj'
Start-Process $DotnetCommand -ArgumentList $DotnetRunCommandApp
```

I get an `InvalidOperationException`:

```
This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Not sure why `Start-Process` can not find the file despite that it do exists in my PATH or even when I give the cmdlt the full path.

---

My end-goal is to be able to specify the params in an object and just pass that object to `Start-Process`. This is part of a pwsh-script that runs on my build-agent to test a webjob-template. Though I want slightly different behaviors locally, see the switch `$Azure` below:

```bsh
$StartProcessParams = @{
  FilePath               = $DotnetCommand
  ArgumentList           = $DotnetRunCommandApp
  RedirectStandardError  = (Resolve-Path $WebJobErrorLogFile)
  RedirectStandardOutput = (Resolve-Path $WebJobLogFile)
  PassThru               = $true;

  # Logging works best if we keep the process in the same "window" on Azure. Locally let the
  # WebJob run in a new windows to make it really easy to kill the process in case of any errors
  NoNewWindow            = $Azure;
}

$WebJobProcess = Start-Process $StartProcessParams
```

Comment: I have tried these answers already but they did not work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434332/use-variable-for-filepath-parameter-of-start-process

Comment: I can't reproduce this in PowerShell 5.1

Comment: @GeorgeChakhidze I'm using powershell core, I updated the question with that info.

Comment: I guess you actually want to use parmeter [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7): `$WebJobProcess = Start-Process @StartProcessParams`

Comment: @iRon Isn't that exactly what my last example is?

Comment: No, you have `$` sign before your variable (`$StartProcessParams`), I have an `@` sign: (`@StartProcessParams`), please read the link about [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7)

Comment: @iRon I totally missed that mistake, thanks for pointing it out! 

Comment: I noticed that you changed it in the question. Does that mean it didn't fix the actual problem?

Comment: @iRon Sorry, I'm a bit distracted today... It indeed fixed the issue. Please write an answer and I will mark it as Accepted. I changed the question back to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @iRon in the comments, the issue is that I am not using [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7) correct. I am using `$StartProcessParams` instead of `@StartProcessParams` (the difference is the first char; `$` vs `@`). This works just fine:

```bsh
$StartProcessParams = @{
  FilePath               = $DotnetCommand
  ArgumentList           = $DotnetRunCommandApp
  RedirectStandardError  = (Resolve-Path $WebJobErrorLogFile)
  RedirectStandardOutput = (Resolve-Path $WebJobLogFile)
  PassThru               = $true;

  # Logging works best if we keep the process in the same "window" on Azure. Locally let the
  # WebJob run in a new windows to make it really easy to kill the process in case of any errors
  NoNewWindow            = $Azure;
}

$WebJobProcess = Start-Process @StartProcessParams
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the help documentation for Start-Process

```
If you specify only a filename, use the WorkingDirectory parameter to specify the path."

The WorkingDirectory Paramter "specifies the location of the executable file or document that runs in the process. The default is the current folder."
```

Try the following command:

```
Start-Process $DotnetCommand -ArgumentList $DotnetRunCommandApp -WorkingDirectory </dir/to/PATH>
```

Your issue may be that it is trying to resolve the variable content 'dotnet' from your current directory, rather than your PATH location.

Comment: I kinda works but not for this specific scenario. `dotnet` needs to be run in the directory I'm standing in to avoid the project using the wrong directory to look for appsettings.json. But it might help others out that is not using `dotnet` specifically, upvoted!